# Plural Category Base Slug On Category Archive Page

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, slug

I've got a little problem with the category base slugs. Say I have got a category called 'Resources', with the category slug set to 'resource'.

So any post in the category resource will appear with this kind of permalink:

example.com/resource/test-post

I have set the base category slug to be just the category slug. Hence, the category archive for the 'resource' category is like this:

example.com/resource/

However, I want the category archive slug to be in plural form like this:

example.com/resources/

Any way to achieve this? I have found nothing re. this problem on Google...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this effect by updating the category slug. Under posts, go to **Categories**. Select the category you are working with and update the slug to "resources". Now, if you visit the category archive for Resource, you should see the URL form thus: `example.com/resources/`.